# How to validate chess moves with a server? Winboard and Unity 2020.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chess

I'm looking for advice on how to implement online chess move validation using a winboard chess engine. I am creating a mobile battle chess game in Unity 2020.3. Right now I have the possible moves for each player, castle rights, check status, etc being generated by an [open source C# chess engine](https://www.chessprogramming.org/NoraGrace).  I chose this engine because it's written in C# and the code could be directly included in my Unity Project. I successfully wrote my own code that connects this chess engine to a 3D battle chess game.

**How the game works** ([video preview](https://youtu.be/Hd-LO8a4Ut0)):

1. A piece is selected by the player clicking it with their mouse or
   tapping the screen.
2. The possible moves for the current board are calculated by the chess engine.
3. I use the possible move indexes to show possible move highlights.
4. When a player makes one of these possible moves, the move is applied on the chess engine.
5. It becomes the other player's turn.

I have some custom code to run player animations, based on the kind of move (ex. an attack animation runs when a piece is captured). I also show have screens that show when it's time for a promotion, a player is in check, or the game is over.

I'd like to somehow make the process of calculating possible moves and applying moves to be done on a server. My goal is to protect from players sending illegal moves to the board and breaking the game.

How would you recommend I approach this problem? This is the last thing I need to turn this game into an enjoyable online experience. I just lack the crucial skill of understanding how to make this game online.

Comment: So why can't you also use that open source chess engine at the server side?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf If it's that simple I would love to do exactly that. Would you be able to explain the steps needed to make the chess engine server sided? I know this is probably a remedial question for anyone with knowledge of servers, but I have no idea where to start. If you could give me a broad idea, I'll learn the technology that's needed to get the chess engine at the server side. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Unfortunately your question is overly broad.  You probably need to look at web services, either hosted on traditional web server, or cloud services.  How are you currently sending moves from one player to the other?  If you already have that, then the other option would be for the others players app to reject any illegal moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server, you'll have a separate version of the chess game running.

A player(/client) will send a move to the server (so a unique piece ID, and the target square the player wants to move).

On the server-side, you'll need to check to see if that move is indeed possible. This could be by getting all possible moves from that piece, and checking to see if the `intendedChessPosition` can be found in the list of `possibleChessPositions` that was calculated on server-side. Only then, will you actually move the piece server-side.

All players/clients will communicate using the server as the middleman and authority.

The exact implementation could change depending on the API of the chess engine you're using, but that's the basic idea.